# Problems intercommunicating processes in c++ using winsock2

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, unix-socket

I am having terrible trouble intercommunicating processes, using `UNIX sockets`. My server is written in `c++`, but I can't get past calling the `bind` method.

`c++` code.

```
OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));

    WCHAR strbuf[256];
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : WSAStartup failed with error: %d", iResult);
        OutputDebugString(strbuf);
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
        return 1;
    }

    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket, addrlen, new_socket, client_socket[30],
        max_clients = 30, activity, i, valread, sd;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    
    char buffer[1025];  //data buffer of 1K

    //set of socket descriptors 
    fd_set readfds;

    TIMEVAL tv = { 2, 0 };

    //a message 
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";

    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked 
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }

    /*struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNIX;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : getaddrinfo failed with error: %d", iResult);
        OutputDebugString(strbuf);
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit 2"));
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }*/

    //create a master socket 
    if ((master_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : socket failed with error"));
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
        return 1;
    }

    //set master socket to allow multiple connections , 
    //this is just a good habit, it will work without this 
    if (setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt,
        sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service : setsockopt failed with error"));
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
        return 1;
    }

    //type of socket created 
    address.sin_family = AF_UNIX;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //I really don't know what to put here
    //address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    ////bind the socket to localhost port 8000 
    //if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    //{
    //  wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : bind failed with error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    //  OutputDebugString(strbuf);
    //  OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit 2"));
    //  closesocket(master_socket);
    //  WSACleanup();
    //  return 1;
    //}

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : bind failed with error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            OutputDebugString(strbuf);
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
            closesocket(master_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
    }

    //freeaddrinfo(result);

    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket 
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
    {
        wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        OutputDebugString(strbuf);
        OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
        closesocket(master_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    //accept the incoming connection 
    
    wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : Listener on port %d", PORT);
    OutputDebugString(strbuf);
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Waiting for connections ..."));

    //  Periodically check if the servC:\Users\Administrator\Desktopice has been requested to stop
    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        /*
        * Perform main service function here
        */

        //clear the socket set 
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        //add master socket to set 
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;

        //add child sockets to set 
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            //socket descriptor 
            sd = client_socket[i];

            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list 
            if (sd > 0)
                FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function 
            if (sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }

        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , 
        //so wait indefinitely 
        activity = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno != EINTR))
        {
            OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: select failed with error"));
        }

        //If something happened on the master socket , 
        //then its an incoming connection 
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket,
                (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : accept failed with error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                OutputDebugString(strbuf);
                OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Exit"));
                closesocket(master_socket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service : New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
            OutputDebugString(strbuf);

            //send new connection greeting message
            if (send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message))
            {
                OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Welcome message sent failed with error"));
            }
            else
            {
                OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: Welcome message sent successfully"));
            }

            //add new socket to array of sockets 
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
            {
                //if position is empty 
                if (client_socket[i] == 0)
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service: Adding to list of sockets as %d", i);
                    OutputDebugString(strbuf);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //else its some IO operation on some other socket
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];

            if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds))
            {
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the 
                //incoming message 
                if ((valread = recv(sd, buffer, 1024, 0)) == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print 
                    getpeername(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, \
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    wsprintfW(strbuf, L"My Sample Service: Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d",
                        inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));
                    OutputDebugString(strbuf);

                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse 
                    closesocket(sd);
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }

                //Echo back the message that came in 
                else
                {
                    //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end 
                    //of the data read 
                    buffer[valread] = '\0';
                    send(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error returned by the `bind` method is `10022`. I only want to accept connections from my own machine. The commented part of the code is because somewhere, I read that for `UNIX sockets`, `getaddrinfo` should not be done. Can someone help me to solve my problem??

I can't find any complete example project of process intercommunication using `winsock` either, if you point me to one it would also be very helpful.

THANK

**EDIT**

I am trying to intercommunicate two processes in `windows`. The link left by [@Hans_Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in the comments, points out that for this I must Download the `Windows Insiders SDK for the Windows build 17061`, but it is not available to everyone, it says: "To access this page, you need to be a member of the Windows Insider Program". so how can I do it?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/

Comment: @HansPassant interesting, I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant please see update.

Comment: That was true only back in 2017, today it is included with any recent Win10 version.  Read the **entire** article, you should already have verified OS support with `sc query afunix` and used `sockaddr_un` in your code.  And do explain why you think you need AF_UNIX support, the feature was only intended to make porting *nix code easy.  That's certainly not what the code snippet looks like.

Comment: sc query afunix

SERVICE_NAME: afunix
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
It seems like it supports it, but still when I #include <afunix.h> I get a cannot open source file. I think I need AF_UNIX support to intercommunicate two processes, specifically c++ and python.

Answer (score 0):

Unix sockets are already local, you must put nothing but the address family in the address:

```
       memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
       my_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
```

Example (source: [doc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)):

```
       int sfd, cfd;
       struct sockaddr_un my_addr, peer_addr;
       socklen_t peer_addr_size;

       sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
       if (sfd == -1)
           handle_error("socket");

       memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
       my_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
       strncpy(my_addr.sun_path, MY_SOCK_PATH,
               sizeof(my_addr.sun_path) - 1);

       if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr,
               sizeof(my_addr)) == -1)
           handle_error("bind");

       if (listen(sfd, LISTEN_BACKLOG) == -1)
           handle_error("listen");

       /* Now we can accept incoming connections one
          at a time using accept(2). */

       peer_addr_size = sizeof(peer_addr);
       cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                    &peer_addr_size);
```

**Update:** I would recommend you to stick to TCP sockets:

```
master_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
```

and then:

```
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;
address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

Listening in the loopback interface ensures that no connections from the outside world will ever reach the socket.

Comment: I am using window platform

Comment: Yes, but you are also using unix sockets. The page I linked in my answer is already referenced by MS's docs. Se Hans Passant's comment above for more details.

Comment: @ldiaz997 Then you won't be able to use Unix sockets in your code (unless you define the relevant constants and structs in your own code).  You will have to use TCP sockets instead (`AF_INET`/`AF_INET6` + `SOCK_STREAM`).

Comment: So you are trying to use unix sockets in a platform that doesn't support it? What compiler are you using?

Comment: That configuration prevents connections from outside my machine? I only want to accept connections from local processes. I am using windows. and visual studio 2017

Comment: Yes, it will only accept connections from the local machine.

Comment: So if this way exists, why do AF_UNIX type sockets exist for ipc? I mean, what's the difference? why the two variants?

Comment: please consider editing your answer, instead of "Considering the comments below", write, "Considering editing..." is for the community.

Comment: `why the two variants?:` INET sockets implement the IPv4 protocol whereas UNIX sockets don't (which would make then lighter and probably work better in some systems).